# How do I empty a DOM object without emptying its children? (dom-construct.empty(myDiv) shallow in FF & Chrome, deep in IE)

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

My map application page has a div dedicated to containing a widget, such as a help window or a list of search results, floating above the map. Either a single widget or nothing is shown at any given time. There's a button for each widget, and clicking it either opens that widget (replacing what was in the div) or closes it if it's the widget that is currently open.

This is one of the functions that handles these button clicks (the aforementioned div is `widgets.main`):

```
_openSearch: function() {
    if (widgets._activeWidget == widgets._searchWidget){
        domConstruct.empty(widgets.main);
        widgets._activeWidget = null;
    } else {
        widgets._searchWidget.show();
        widgets._activeWidget = widgets._searchWidget;
    }
},
```

This is the function that gets called:

```
show: function() {
    domConstruct.empty(this.rootDiv);
    this.rootDiv.appendChild(this.widgetDiv);
},
```

`widget.widgetDiv` is the div element with the actual content of the widget. My intention was to generate the content once, then keep it stored in `widgetDiv` if the widget is closed. This works as expected in IE and Chrome, but IE (IE8 in particular) gets rid of everything inside `widgetDiv` when `domConstruct.empty()` is called.

How do I get the desired behavior in IE? Also, which behavior is the "right" one, standards-wise?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question or problem is. You're calling `domConstruct.empty()` on `this.rootDiv`, but `this.widgetDiv` is the node being cleared? [According to the docs](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dom-construct.html#dojo-dom-construct-empty), `domConstruct.empty()` always deletes the children of the given node but keeps the parent node in place.

Comment: The `rootDiv` is either empty or has exactly one child. I don't actually want to destroy the child, just to detach it so that it can be exchanged with another one, like switching photos in a picture frame.

Firefox and Chrome behave the way I expected, but IE removes the contents of the child as well. I appreciate that this may be the way `domConstruct.empty()` is supposed to work, but the fact that it behaves differently in different browsers confuses me (and I still need to know whether I'm overlooking something or whether I need to look for other ways of acheiving the desired functionality)

Comment: You could just use `this.rootDiv.removeChild(...)` ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild)), which returns the removed node, to keep a reference to the child nodes you want to add back when exchanging.

Comment: Thanks, that does just what I need. If you'll post an answer about it, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dojo's `domConstruct.empty()` ([see docs here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dom-construct.html#dojo-dom-construct-empty)) just destroys all children – it actually sets `innerHTML` to an empty string for non-SVG elements.

`removeChild` may be a little less performant but it seems to fit your use case a little better, since it returns the removed nodes. Perhaps something like the following would work:

```
show: function() {
    // save a reference to the current children of rootDiv to use later
    var oldChild = this.rootDiv.removeChild(this.rootDiv.firstChild);

    this.rootDiv.appendChild(this.widgetDiv);
}
```

Make sure that `rootDiv` has exactly one child that you want to save. If it doesn't, you could wrap it in a `<div>`.